# Does this (small) snippet of code correctly prevent API KEY timing attacks? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am implementing API KEY authentication/authorization for an API project I am creating. I am making use of the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method call and guarding against timing attacks. I read about timing attacks for the first time and I've tried to implement that safe guard in my `ApplicationController`. I believe I have the mechanism done correctly but would like confirmation. Here is the snippet of code.

```
before_action :authenticate_request

def authenticate_request
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    api_key = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token)
    secret_key = ApiKey.find(api_key.id).secret_key
    api_key.present? && (api_key.active != false) && secure_compare_with_hashing(api_key.secret_key, secret_key)
  end
end

def secure_compare_with_hashing(key1, key2)
  ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(key1, key2)
end
```

Basically, I am 1). Finding the Api key by the token submitted in the header, 2). I am then finding using the id of the api_key to retrieve the secret key. 3). I am comparing the secret key of both values for time constant comparison.

If I am not mistaken, I believe that this should satisfy the successful mitigation of timing attacks. Am I correct in this?

====== update ======

For context, I am using this resource to address the timing error [Timing Attack Prevention](https://devblast.com/r/master-ruby-web-apis/clients-authentication#cid5). Here is a small paragraph quote from the online book.

> The way we implemented the API key is vulnerable to timing attacks. That’s why many web APIs come with an access key and a secret key. The access key can be used to find the record in the database before doing a secure comparison of the secret keys.

> In order to check whether or not an API key is valid in a safe way, we need to retrieve the database record without using the actual token. Indeed, doing a SQL query like ApiKey.where(key: 'abc') is vulnerable to timing attacks.

> To avoid this, we can ask the client to provide us with another way to find the record, for example by sending the key id. We would end up with receiving api_key=1:abc instead of api_key=abc, where 1 is a API key id.

> For a real-world application, we should have created a new field to save an access key instead of using the id.

Here is the code that I am trying to adapt.

```
module Authentication
  include ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils
  # Hidden Code

  included # Hidden Code

  private

  def validate_auth_scheme # Hidden Code
  def unauthorized! # Hidden Code
  def authorization_request # Hidden Code

  def credentials
    @credentials ||= Hash[authorization_request.scan(/(\w+)[:=] ?"?([\w|:]+)"?/)]
  end

  def api_key
    @api_key ||= compute_api_key
  end

  def compute_api_key
    return nil if credentials['api_key'].blank?

    id, key = credentials['api_key'].split(':')
    api_key = id && key && ApiKey.activated.find_by(id: id)

    return api_key if api_key && secure_compare_with_hashing(api_key.key, key)
  end

  def secure_compare_with_hashing(a, b)
    secure_compare(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(a), Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(b))
  end

end
```

Does my code not properly follow this procedure? Ignoring the problm case where my code doesn't return the key, does the comparison of the secret_key make sense?

For example,

```
api_key = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token) #Timing attack :(
```

I get the secret key using the api_key that I found.

```
secret_key = ApiKey.find(api_key.id).secret_key
```

Timing attack circumvented.

```
secure_compare_with_hashing(api_key.secret_key, secret_key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secure_compare` prevents timing attacks by converting your strings into equally long hashes so this should be fine.

However, I'm wondering what the code before does.

Is this snippet not fetching the same `ApiKey` twice? Also there is a bug in your implementation when the token does not exist.

```rb
api_key = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token)
secret_key = ApiKey.find(api_key.id).secret_key # this will crash if token does not exist

secure_compare_with_hashing(api_key.secret_key, secret_key) # is always true, no?
```

Also, this will do an early return. Although it's not possible to guess the whole password one can still get information if the api_key exists for instance.

```rb
api_key.present? && (api_key.active != false)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe76a95b0d252a2d7c25e69498b720c96b243ea2/activesupport/lib/active_support/security_utils.rb#L27

## Edit

Comparing with the tutorial you provided you did exactly what you shouldn't do.

```rb
def authenticate_request
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    api_key = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: token) # <- TIMING ATTACK ON DB
    # ...
  end
end
```

Instead what you should do is provide the user / key id in the options and use it to fetch the key from the database. I also flipped your conditional to always do the secure compare and do the active check at the end.

```rb
def authenticate_request
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    api_key = ApiKey.find_by(id: options[:key_id])

   secure_compare_with_hashing(api_key&.secret_key.to_s, token) &&
     api_key.active
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Christian, thank you for answering my question, could you take a look at my update? Aside from the bug where the key is not found or disabled, did I bypass the timing attack? I am grabbing the key provided in the token, looking up the secret key and then comparing the secret key.  I did notice the secure compare always returns true which I found it odd in the example that i am adapting from.

Comment: As another update, essentially I want to do this summed up perfectly in the book. <"That’s why many web APIs come with an access key and a secret key. The access key can be used to find the record in the database before doing a secure comparison of the secret keys">

Comment: You basically just c&p the snippet from the book, so yes this seems to be not vulnerable to timing attacks. If this answered your question please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Updated my initial answer.